# How to setup separate theme for mac-book 13 half size screen

Tags: magento2.3, theme, custom, mobile, macbook

I created two separate theme for mobile and the Desktop on the live server.
When I am assign Mobile user string to the Mobile theme in admin backend then Ipad layout doesn't work.

If i assign Mobile string to the Desktop top then mobile css doesn't work.
If i resized my macbook 13 half then desktop css should be apply.
Please help me o find correct user string name for macbook half sized screen.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way, there is little case for having a separate mobile and desktop theme. You should build a single theme that is responsive else you're duplicating the effort required for very little gain.

> We can quarantine the mobile experience on separate subdomains, spaces distinct and separate from “the non-iPhone website.” But what’s next? An iPad website? An N90 website? Can we really continue to commit to supporting each new user agent with its own bespoke experience? At some point, this starts to feel like a zero sum game. But how can we—and our designs—adapt?

https://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/